# Naming Estate Accounts

Tags: united-states, trusts-and-estates, death

Joe Smith (a fictional person) dies with several brokerage accounts and a living revocable trust. The trust has several brokerage accounts also. The name of the trust is Smith Living Trust. Now, estate accounts have to be opened for Joe Smith's accounts.

For his individual accounts, is it okay (legal/proper) to use the name:
Joe Smith Estate

For accounts owned by the trust, is it okay (legal/proper) to use the name:
Smith Living Trust Estate

If these names are not proper/legal to use, what would be proper/legal to use?